# Question 1.18 of Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Show that $I=(x^2+1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$ is not an ideal of any set in $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

My soluion- if there exists some set $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $I=I(X)$ then we will have $X\subseteq V(I(X))=V(x^2+1)=\phi$. Forcing $X=\phi$ and $I=I(\phi)=\mathbb{R}[x]$, a contradiction.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: I think this is correct. Is there a step you're unsure about?